# Power BI Report Server : Extension Custom Security : How to add/register admin user (no AD)

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, power-bi-report-server

I just installed the Custom Security extension on my Power BI Report Server
I registered through the web page into the UserAccounts database but I don't know how I can add the first admin user (no ActiveDirectory) in the internal Report Server database.

Could you please help me with this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have used [Microsoft Github page for CustomSecuritySample](https://github.com/microsoft/Reporting-Services/tree/master/CustomSecuritySample). If so, the user which is considered as *admin* is defined in RSReportServer.config file, located in the \ReportServer directory:

```
<Security>
    <Extension Name="Forms" Type="Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.CustomSecurity.Authorization, Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.CustomSecurity" >
    <Configuration>
        <AdminConfiguration>
            <UserName>myuser</UserName>
        </AdminConfiguration>
    </Configuration>
    </Extension>
</Security>
```

In the above example, **myuser** is considered admin.